# How to return the index corresponding to the person with the biggest time

Tags: java, output

The below code has an array for names (racers in a marathon) and in the other array I have the time array for each (racer) to finish the race ...
I want to return the index corresponding to the person with the biggest time.
My code does return the biggest time but it returns the biggest time for all names (racers) ... The biggest time should be returned for one racer ...

```
class Marathon {

        public static void main (String[] arguments) {
            int biggest = 0;
            String[] names = {
                "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex",
                "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda",
                "Aaron", "Kate"
            };

            int[] times = {
                341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299,
                343, 317, 265
            };

            for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
                if (times[i] > biggest) {
                    biggest=times[i];
                }
                System.out.println(names[i]+":"+biggest);

           }
         }
       }
```

The output I got is :

```
Elena:445
Thomas:445
Hamilton:445
Suzie:445
Phil:445
Matt:445
Alex:445
Emma:445
John:445
James:445
Jane:445
Emily:445
Daniel:445
Neda:445
Aaron:445
Kate:445
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues :

- you assume the result *before* computing it
- you are looking for a maximum so the initial value should be as small as possible (0, for example, because it is a time)
- you should store the index of the largest time, not only the largest time itself
- you should not print in your loop since you only want to print the name of the runner with the longest time (so a single print)

Comment: Hi .. I did int biggest=0; but how to store the index of the largest time , do I have to use another array [] or a ArrayList outside the main method??

Comment: Instead of storing the time itself you should store the index of the time.

Comment: In the same way as you stored the biggest time: use a variable like `biggest_index` that stores the index of the biggest time found so far. And every time when you found a time greater than the one found so far you update that index variable.

Comment: I did think about it before but I can not store the index of the largest time because names[] is a String ... I do not know how to connect the index of the largest time and the largest time itself ... Can you write a code about that ??

Comment: You just need to store the value of `i` when you find the maximum. You need to add a single line to your code

Comment: how ? is it like this return names(i); if it is not can you write it for me .. thanks

Comment: You have a brain, I can only tell you the principle. I'm sorry to be tough, but you will never be a programmer if you cannot apply what I have said to you. I won't give you any code to copy-paste. My answer and comments contain everything you need